# Best Way to Include Variable in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just wondering what the bests way to include variables in printed-lines.

For example would it be better to do:

```
print("The cost will be $" + str(cost) + ".")
```

or

```
print("The cost will be ${}.".format(cost))
```

Thanks, 
David

P.S. when explaining, note that I am new at programming in general, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

I would say currently, this is better:

```
print("The cost will be ${}.".format(cost))
```

Because no need for converting for string.

Note: if your python version is over 3.5, do `print(f'The cost will be${cost}')`, because it's the best.

Note there are several other ways that are equally good (with all versions):

```
print('The cost will be$%s'%cost)
```

Or (maybe not equally good..):

```
print("The cost will be $",cost,".",sep='')
```

Comment: As of 3.6 f-strings are nicer.  `print(f'The cost will be ${cost}')`

Comment: @GWW I 'll edit

Comment: @GWW Done the edit!!!